# How to run XGBoostregressor using reg: tweedie as objective?

Tags: python, regression, xgboost, python-3.x, anaconda

I installed XGBoost for anaconda on windows 10 based on the instructions provided [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_For_Anaconda_on_Windows?lang=en). It seems that xgboost 0.6 is already installed. It performs well using "`reg:linear`". However, if I use "`reg:tweedie`", this error is reported:

```
xgboost.core.XGBoostError: b'[23:08:27] src/objective/objective.cc:21: Unknown objective function reg:tweedie'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, it is a versioning issue. However, it should be noted that before installing the latest version, the old version should be manually removed. Then, try to install the new version.

Comment: Try `print(xgboost.__version__)` to make sure the version you are using is the correct one.